# Compilation for ARM and X86 using buildroot

Tags: buildroot

I have a buildroot-based project where a package is compiled for the target system using an ARM compiler, and another project, the unit tests, which are based on the same code. This other project uses the host compiler, which appears to be the compiler from my system.

I'd rather it be an X86 version of the ARM cross-compiler, so the compiler versions are the same, regardless of the compiler that's on the system.

Can anyone tell me how to setup this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want them to be the same, it's best to use the same buildroot configuration (at least the toolchain part) for the unit tests as well, and run it in qemu instead of on the target. You may need a separate kernel to run in qemu. You can use one of the qemu defconfigs within Buildroot as a starting point.

Comment: That's a good idea. In absence of any other answers, I'll accept this in a few days.